# calling an activity class from Async class

Tags: android

I am trying to call a new activity class has below from Async class that i used for webservice,i am not able to remove the error coming on intent prompting to remove if loop,i am new to android i am not sure if i am doing correct.I just need to call a activity class after webservice call passing the output data to activity.

```
 private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask < String, Void, Void > {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String...params) {
        //Invoke webservice
        vaildUserId = WebService.invokeAuthenticateUserWS(loginUserName, loginPassword, "AuthenticateUser");
        if (vaildUserId >= 0) {
            System.out.println("userId---" + vaildUserId);
            List < GetReminder > reminderList = WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS("GetReminder");
            if (reminderList.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < reminderList.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("displayText---" + reminderList.get(i).getRemMessage() + "ff" + reminderList.size()); * * reminderIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderActivity.class); * * startActivity(reminderIntent);
                }
            } else {
                //no invoice found
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: don't call intent in `doInBackground()` use `onPost()` instead.

Comment: u mean onPostExecute()

Comment: @maveň http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215730/server-not-able-to-read-parameters-while-making-a-webservice-connection any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update UI from background thread.

You should move your code to start Activity from `doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute()`

Comment: i am calling two services in doInBackground,,and i have single onPostExecute(),how will i manipulate result?

Comment: What do you mean? You are trying to start Same Activity in a for loop.You should set some variables & pass it to onPostExecute().Depending on the result start the Activty.

Comment: Ok.Will do.But why are you using for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method to call [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) in main (UI) thread as this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
          startActivity(reminderIntent);
    }
});
```